# How can i run perl script from anywhere in unix environment?

Tags: perl, unix

I have this perl script that I need to distribute to my coworkers who want to run the script from anywhere in the unix environment. What can I do on my part to make running this PERL script easy for them? For example, they can just have the PERL script somewhere in their directory and run just typing

```
./xyz.pl ttt.conf
```

with no path declared (like /home/abc/bin/ddd/xyz.pl ttt.conf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I used to do it is add a "bin" directory in your home directory, and add it to the `$PATH` variable.. then you can add any script you want to use to that directory.

I am no longer familiar with the exact syntax, but something like:

in .bashrc:

```
$PATH = ( $PATH , $HOME/bin )
```

Then place the script in `/home/user/bin` (assuming $HOME == /home/user). When you reload the shell, it will be usable like any normal command/program.

ETA: See robert's comment below on syntax. Also, to allow your co-workers to use a script of yours, you can simply use a hard-coded path, such as `/home/patrick/bin`.

Comment: syntax for sh and bash: `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"; export $PATH`; for csh: `setenv PATH "$HOME/bin:$PATH"`.

Comment: @TLP : I am having the same question and I have modified the PATH variable also. But I am having errors when I directly use, the perl executable file. And the same file works perfectly, when I execute "perl ~/bin/<Perl Filename>"

Answer (score 5):

Put the script in `/usr/local/bin` (or anywhere else in `$PATH`).  Your sysadmin may have to help you.

Answer (score 5):

The technique I use is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

This is a common way of getting the command interpreter to find Perl without either (a) moving the file, or (b) declaring the explicit path for Perl in the shebang.

It's mentioned under portability at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: Adding a shebang line at the top of your script will let you run the script as `./script` instead of `path/to/perl script` or `perl script`. The OP is asking how to run the script from anywhere.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, the OP's example is in the form ./script - that's why a shebang is needed. This is the way to make that work without hardwiring the path to Perl into the script.

Answer (score 2):

You all are kind of right...  but that perl script can sit in your path till the cows come home... and it ain't gonna run... until you set the executable bit....

```
:bin localadmin$ ./perlextip
-bash: ./perlextip: Permission denied
:bin localadmin$ chmod +x perlextip 
:bin localadmin$ ./perlextip 
Exit 0!  Yeehaw.
```

Also, it should be noted that it need not be IN your path.... You can just call it by the full path, preceeded with a period and a slash, to execute it..

```
:/ localadmin$ ./ServiceData/UNIX/bin/extip
Exit 0!  Yeehaw.
```

You can also create an alias for such a command in your `~/.bash_profile`, or the such, which will let you make a system-wide shortcut of sorts, and you can even throw in a sudo, or the like, if you were so inclined... Then just call that "extip" by name anywhere, you'll be prompted for a password and, all will be well in the world.

```
alias extip='sudo ./ServiceData/UNIX/bin/extip'
```